# ¿Cómo puedo asignar un pedazo de código para llamarlo más adelante?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
me gustaría poder guardar todo el código como una variable para por ej, tener una lista oculta y mostrarla sólo si el usuario logra pasar todo el código asignado, en este caso (registrarse e ingresar los datos registrados). algo así como
   if código_registro = superado_éxito:
      print(lista_datos_importantes). espero me entiendan




import time
import getpass


print("Bienvenido a ALGO, ahora ingresa tus datos a registrar")
Usuario_Guardado = input("Ingrese su Usuario: ")
Contraseña_Guardada = getpass.getpass("Ingrese su Contraseña: ")
print("Datos almacenados correctamente")

print("Ahora ingrese sus datos para confirmar su identidad")


max_intentos = 3
intentos = 0
while intentos < max_intentos:
    Usuario_Ingresado = input("Ingrese su usuario: ")
    if Usuario_Ingresado == Usuario_Guardado:
        print("Usuario correcto")
        break
    else: print("Usuario incorrecto, te quedan {} intentos".format(max_intentos - intentos - 1))
    intentos = intentos + 1

    if intentos == max_intentos:
        print("Has alcanzado el máximo número de intentos")
        quit()

max_intentos = 3
intentos = 0
while intentos < max_intentos:
    Contraseña_Ingresada = getpass.getpass("Ingrese su contraseña: ")
    if Contraseña_Ingresada == Contraseña_Guardada:
        print("Contraseña correcta")
        break
    else: print("Contraseña incorrecta, le quedan {} intentos".format(max_intentos - intentos -1))
    intentos = intentos + 1

    if intentos == max_intentos:
        print("Has alcanzado el máximo número de intentos")
        quit()

print("Has ingreado con éxito")
```

Comment: Hola JGUser no termino de entender lo que pretendes, si quieres ejecutar cierto código desde otra parte puedes envolverlo en una función y llamarla. No se que quieres decir con "lista oculta", ¿oculta para el usuario simplemente pero visible en el código?, ¿datos encriptados en disco, base de datos, etc?

Comment: al inicio de todo quiero poner lista_amigos = ["Luis", "Carlos"] print(lista_amigos). pero quiero que ese print se ejecute cuando se logre pasar todo el codigo de registro y log. cómo puedo envolver en una función?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La normal es crear una función que una vez definida puedes llamar en cualquier momento que la necesites.

---

- Para crear una función se usa la instrucción `def` más un nombre descriptivo seguido de paréntesis de apertura y cierre (que contendrán los nombres de los parámetros si se necesitan) y por último se cierra con `:`. El código a ejecutar cuando la función sea llamada va identado con un nivel más que la linea del `def` .
- Una función puede recibir  parámetros que irán separados por una coma entre los paréntesis, a modo de variables para poder utilizarlos como tales (variables locales) dentro de la misma función. En Python una función puede recibir cualquier objeto como parámetro, incluida otra función. Se permite pasar parámetros por *keywords*, parámetros opcionales y también se puede hacer que una función reciba un número arbitrario de parámetros (desconocido a priori).
- Toda función retorna algo cuando es llamada y que puede ser almacenado en una variable. Por defecto toda función/método retorna `None`, si necesitamos que la función retorne algo se usa `return` seguido del objeto a retornar. La ejecución de `return` causa que la función termine inmediatamente en ese punto, aunque quede código por ejecutar en ella.
- El código contenido en una función no es ejecutado hasta el momento en el que es llamada. Para llamar a una función basta con su nombre seguido de paréntesis, que contendrán los argumentos si los requieren: `mi_función(argumento1, argumento2`).

Esto sería lo básico, por no hacer de la respuesta un tutorial no voy a profundizar más. Un ejemplo simple:

```
def sumar(n, m):
    suma = n + m
    return suma

# Llamamos a la función e imprimimos su retorno
print(sumar(4, 7))  # Nos imprimirá 11

# Llamamos a la función y guardamos su retorno en una variable:
resultado = suma(4, 7)
print(resultado)
```

---

En tu caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
# Defines tu lista como variable global, la cual podrá modificar si lo necesitas
lista_amigos = ["Luis", "Carlos"]

# Defines tu función
def print_amigos():
    print(lista_amigos)

# Posteriormente, cuando el usuario se autentifique simplemente la llamas 
print_amigos()
```

Si necesitas que el código actúe de forma diferente en función de ciertas variables puedes hacer que la función acepte parámetros. En este caso en función del usuario ingresado (que pasamos como argumento a la función) la respuesta será diferente, acorde a los datos disponibles para ese usuario (almacenados en un diccionario):

```
datos = {"Pedro": {"amigos": ["Luis", "Carlos"]},
         "Laura": {"amigos": ["Maria", "Raquel", "Miguel"]},
         "Leonardo": {"amigos": []}}

def print_amigos(usuario):
    print("Usuario: {}.".format(usuario))

    if not usuario in datos:
        print("[ERROR]: Usuario no registrado")
        return

    amigos = datos[usuario]["amigos"]
    if amigos:
        print("  Tiene {} amigos registrados:".format(len(amigos)))
        for amigo in amigos:
            print("    - {}.".format(amigo))
        return

    print("  Aún no tiene amigos resgistrados")


usr = input("Ingrese su usuario: ")
print_amigos(usr)
```

Ejemplos de salida:

```
Ingrese su usuario: Pedro
Usuario: Pedro.
  Tiene 2 amigos registrados:
    - Luis.
    - Carlos.

Ingrese su usuario: Laura
Usuario: Laura.
  Tiene 3 amigos registrados:
    - Maria.
    - Raquel.
    - Miguel.

Ingrese su usuario: Leonardo
Usuario: Leonardo.
  Aún no tiene amigos resgistrados

Ingrese su usuario: Raquel
Usuario: Raquel.
[ERROR]: Usuario no registrado
```